# SQL Query To Display Mobile number that are registered in Different Mobile Network

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am suffering from a situation where a user has changed his mobile network and subscribed our service but their mobile number is same. So, for his old subscription I have his old mobile network and for his new subscription, I have his new mobile network record.

For example

```
4474123456  subscribed  gamesClub  using O2 network on 2013-10-20
4474123456  subscribed  musicClub  using Orange network on 2013-12-05
```

Therefore, I want to display these kind of mobile numbers who have subscribed our services using different network.

```
Database: MySQL
Table :  MobileUsers
field:
userunique,mobileno, subscription,networkname, subscribedDate
```

Query I have tried

```
 SELECT mobileno,networkname,count(*) from MobileUsers 
 group by mobileno,networkname

 SELECT mobileno,count(*) from MobileUsers group by mobileno,networkname
```

But none of the results are satisfactory. These also include mobileno who have multiple subscriptions having the same network.

Thank You,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use `GROUP BY/HAVING`:

```
SELECT  MobileNo
FROM    MobileUsers 
GROUP BY MobileNo
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT networkname) > 1 -- MORE THAN ONE NETWORK
```

If you then need to get all records back for these mobile numbers, you would need to put the above in a subquery and join back to it:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    MobileUsers m
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  MobileNo
            FROM    MobileUsers 
            GROUP BY MobileNo
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT networkname) > 1 -- MORE THAN ONE NETWORK
        ) Dupe
            ON dupe.MobileNo = m.MobileNo
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery.

```
Select userunique, mobileno, subscription, networkname, subscribedDate
From MobileUsers as t1
Where exists
(
SELECT *
FROM MobileUsers as t2
WHERE t2.mobileno=t1.mobileno and t1.networkname<>t2.networkname
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mobileno,count(*) as no 
from MobileUsers 
group by mobileno

minus

SELECT mobileno,count(*) as no 
from MobileUsers 
group by mobileno,networkname
```